# iOS8 (BOOL)shouldAutorotate not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, autorotate

I am allocating a navigation controller and setting the root view to be a view controller that has a webview, then pushing the navigation controller.

I need this new screen to not allow rotation.  From what I've read `-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate` is where I return `NO` to ignore rotations, but its never called.  How can ignore rotations on this one screen?

Comment: if you use the built-in navigation delegate method, make sure to set delegate of navigation controller to nil when the child controller is popped from the navigation controller

Comment: I edited my answer to respond to your comment.